# How to write your program more efficiently

Tags: c, performance

I have written a code for adding three numbers and printing their sum. Is there a way in which I can write this code more efficiently like initializing and introducing each variable together.

Code goes as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int firstNumber;
  firstNumber = 0;
  printf("Enter firstNumber");
  scanf("%d", &firstNumber);

  int secondNumber;
  secondNumber = 0;
  printf("Enter secondNumber");
  scanf("%d", &secondNumber);

  int thirdNumber;
  thirdNumber = 0;
  printf("Enter thirdNumber");
  scanf("%d", &thirdNumber);

  int sum;
  sum = firstNumber + secondNumber + thirdNumber;
  printf("%d", sum);
}
```

Comment: `int firstnumber = 0;`... etc.

Comment: You could save three line by initializing the variables at definition. You could also save another two lines by not having the `sum` variable at all, and have the addition in the `printf` call. But will it make the generated code more "efficient"? No. No it wont.

Comment: How to write int firstNumber and firstNumber = 0 in one line

Comment: Why wont it change efficiency? Whats efficiency then? I thought its the num of steps

Comment: `int firstNumber=0,secondNumber=0,thirdNumber=0;`

Comment: this is introducing variables plus initializing, right?

Comment: No matter where you initialize the variables, the code will do the same thing. Also, the big thing here is not the initializations or the additions, it's the waiting for the user to input the values. The output is the next bit thing that will "slow" down the program. The rest will be unmeasurable and will feel instantaneous.

Comment: So it makes no difference to this code's time complexity?

Comment: *# steps* != *# lines of code*. And *steps* is not a good term, instead *instructions*.

Comment: Got it. Thanks iharob :)

Comment: Since this code will spend 99.9999999999% of its time in `printf` and `scanf`, you can try all you want to make it faster, and you'll never see any difference.

Answer (score 5):

> can write this code more efficiently like initializing and introducing each variable together.

Use an array:

```
int numbers[3] = {0};
```

The above line defines three `int`s and initialises all of them to `0`.

To access the 1st use:

```
numbers[0]
```

---

If for any reasons your code needs to refer to "*first*", "*second*" and "*third*" create an enumeration to access the array's elements like this:

```
enum Numbers
{
  FirstNumber,
  SecondNumber,
  ThirdNumber
}
```

Then the source code to access the the 2nd number could look like this:

```
numbers[SecondNumber]
```

---

If you want to have the size of `Numbers` follow the number of entries in `enum Numbers` modify the examples above like follows:

```
enum Numbers
{
  FirstNumber,
  SecondNumber,
  ThirdNumber,
  MaxNumbers
}
```

and then define numbers like

```
int Numbers[MaxNumbers] = {0};
```

---

Following the same concept you now can define user prompts for the numbers defined:

```
const char * prompts[MaxNumbers] = {
  "firstNumber",
  "secondNumer",
  "thirdNumber"
};
```

Now everything is in place to also significantly reduce the lines of source code by looping around the input function (instead of coding the more or less same stuff for each number):

Read in:

```
 for (enum Numbers n = 0; n < MaxNumbers; ++n)
 {
   printf("Please enter %s:\n", prompts[n]);
   scanf("%d", &Numbers[n]);
 }
```

Sum up:

```
 int sum = 0;

 for (enum Numbers n = 0; n < MaxNumbers; ++n)
 {
   sum += Numbers[n];
 }

 printf("The sum is: %d\n", sum);
```

The two loops however can be merged into one:

```
 for (enum Numbers n = 0; n < MaxNumbers; ++n)
 {
   printf("Please enter %s:\n", prompts[n]);
   scanf("%d", &Numbers[n]);
   sum += Numbers[n];
 }
```

As a in final note, and left for your studies, be aware that `scanf()` might very well fail. It indicates this by its return value. This the code then can read, detect a possible failure and act accordingly.

Comment: @neoaggelos: Too much of what, please?

Comment: Didn't mean to appear rude, friend mine. I just thought that for reading three numbers, using enums and helper arrays is not worth the time.

Comment: The code shown just mimics the OP code's behaviour. @neoaggelos

Answer (score 3):

In the majority of all coding, the efficiency of the resulting program is less important than factors like readability, maintainability and - most important - correctness.

You should focus on such things first. Only in case the resulting program has a performance problem, you should reconsider you source code. Modern compilers are very good at optimizing so often it doesn't matter much for the resulting efficiency how the source code looks.

In your case, i.e. a program reading from stdin, there is absolutely no reason to change your code in order to get a more efficient program.

However, you may consider a change for better maintainability. For instance, if you need to change the program to add 5 values instead of just 3, how easy is that? It is not easy with the current code.

Using a loop would make it much easier, like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_VARS_TO_ADD 3  // Here you decide how many numbers to add

int main()
{
  int j;
  int d = 0;
  int sum = 0;

  for (j=0; j<NUMBER_OF_VARS_TO_ADD; ++j)
  {
      printf("Enter Number: ");
      scanf("%d", &d);     // This is not good - se later
      sum += d;
  }
  printf("Sum: %d", sum);
}
```

With this code it is easy to change from sum-of-3 to sum-of-N. That is much more important than thinking about efficiency. Notice that this code doesn't store each value read from stdin. It just calculates the sum while reading the values.

Then correctness is important. The way you read in the values are not good. First of all you don't check the value returned by `scanf`. You should always do that! Your current program will give unexpected result if the user type something like `5 d 3`

When you add check of the value returned by `scanf`, you'll soon find that you need to flush stdin after `scanf` in case `scanf` didn't return 1. You need to add such code for correctness. Again much more important than considering efficiency.

Instead of `scanf` a better/easier way is to use `fgets` and `sscanf`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
   int i;    
   int Numbers[3]= {0};
   int sum;
   /*int numberCount; if the count should be dynamic*/
   /*printf("Enter the count of numbers: ");*/
   /*scanf("%d",&numberCount);*/

   for(i=0; i<3;i++)  /*use numberCount instead of 3*/
    {
       printf("Enter Number %d",i);
       scanf("%d", &Number[i]);
       sum += Number[0];
    }
   printf("%d", sum);

}
```

Comment: Proper indention  would be nice.

Comment: "*`... += Number[0];`*": Are you sure? ;-)

Comment: @alk you nailed the issue..... :)
i have checked the code once again...
please let me know if there are more of them...

Answer (score 0):

I find it very usefull to check the generated code at https://gcc.godbolt.org, using allways -O3 or -Ofast.

Without changing your requirements (asking one number at a time with exact same text). It ends up having only two more instructions on intel gcc 6.2 and using ARM gcc 4.82 it actually gets much smaller:

```
// Type your code here, or load an example.
#include <stdio.h>

static inline int readNum(const char * const msg)
{
    int num;
    (void)printf(msg);
    (void)scanf("%d", &num);
    return num;
}

int main()

{
  (void)printf("%d", readNum("Enter firstNumber") + readNum("Enter secondNumber") + 
               readNum("Enter tirdNumber"));

}
```

By changing the spec a little bit we can benefit even more (in this case both intel and arm generates more compact code).

```
// Type your code here, or load an example.
#include <stdio.h>

static inline int readNum(void)
{
    int num;
    (void)printf("Enter a number");
    (void)scanf("%d", &num);
    return num;
}

int main()

{
  (void)printf("%d", readNum() + readNum() + 
               readNum());

}
```

At last if you can ask all the numbers at once. This generates 26 lines output only on x86-64 gcc 6.2 against 43 on the original code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;
    (void)printf("Enter 3 numbers:");
    (void)scanf("%d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3);
    (void)printf("%d", num1 + num2 + num3);

}
```

Comment: What's the use these `(void)<function call>`s, please?

Comment: Potential UB - **always** check the value returned by `scanf` !

Comment: just to point out that the return is being ignored (as it was in the original code of the question). I forgot to add those in the last code though.